# Showing list column in search results

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, administration, 2019, sharepoint-search

We just transitioned to SharePoint 2019 on-prem, and we have a contact list that we use for our employee directory (our organization doesn't use active directory).

The Locations aren't showing in search results, and I wonder if I need to create a managed property for that column.

My question - can I create a managed property for an existing column?  When I view the list of properties to show in the search results, the Location isn't one of the options.  Or, is there something else I need to do get Locations to show as an option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a "site" column, SharePoint automatically creates the managed property for it.

When you create a "list" column, SharePoint does not create the managed property for it.

When you create a column (site/list) and add data in those columns, SharePoint automatically creates the "crawled" property for it when search crawl runs after adding the data.

Here is what you have to do for your list columns:

1. Go to site settings > Search schema and create a new managed property
2. Map the managed property with the related crawled properties from managed property settings
3. Set other settings like searchable/filterable/retrievable/sortable, etc. as per your requirements
4. Use managed property names (not crawled property names or [internal names](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)) in search results to get the column data

Check below documentations for more information:

1. [Overview of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview)
2. [Manage the search schema in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema)